# C++ Poco SQL query does not return results with 'between' and 'and' datetime binding

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I have the following code, where from and to are passed as std::string& and they are datetime in SQL db table, e.g., 2019-04-10

If I run the following, no results are returned:

```
sql_select  << "SELECT asset, sum(amount*price) as total_cost, 
sum(amount) as total_amount FROM tradehistory_bitfinex where uid = ? 
and exchange = ? and time between ?  and ?   group by asset",
                 Poco::Data::Keywords::into(portfolio),
                 Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(uid),
                 Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(exchange);
                 //Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(from),
                 //Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(to);
```

If I run the following, it returns results correctly:

```
sql_select  << "SELECT asset, sum(amount*price) as total_cost, 
sum(amount) as total_amount FROM tradehistory_bitfinex where uid = ? 
and exchange = ? and time between '2019-04-10'  and '2019-04-10'   
group by asset",
                 Poco::Data::Keywords::into(portfolio),
                 Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(uid),
                 Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(exchange);
                 //Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(from),
                 //Poco::Data::Keywords::bind(to);
```

It seems to be something wrong with the datetime / string binding.

Thanks.

Comment: issue resolved: the from/to was not parsed correctly and sent with null value

Answer (score 0):

GoQuestion:

> Issue resolved: the from/to was not parsed correctly and sent with null value.